# Asciidoc/Asciidoctor to LaTeX, LaTeX in Asciidoc

Tags: conversion

Does anybody have experience in using Asciidoc in relation to LaTeX? I am especially interested in

- converting Asciidoc (or the Docbook output) to LaTeX
- using formulae in Asciidoc and process them with LaTeX.

What would be a reliable approach?

Comment: I think the best work flow is: AsciiDoc --> [`DocBook`](http://docbook.org/) --> [`Dblatex`](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/). Going directly from AsciiDoc to *TeX sounds difficult.